# Windows 10 default input method always resetted to English (currently using Korean IME)

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, ime

I'm currently using Windows 10 in my laptop. Since I'm Korean, I've installed the Korean keyboard input layout on an English version of Windows 10. However, every time I log in or reboot the PC, the default keyboard input is always resetted to ENG (United States, US Keyboard), and I have to manually change it to Korean (Microsoft IME), which makes me angry.

**How can I set Korean IME as my default keyboard input?**

**Help!**

[image]

Comment: "Region & Language" has "Advanced Keyboard Settings", that should do it.

Answer (score 3):

After 1803 update, there is BUG in advanced keyboard settings. If you have set override default input method, it will not re-apply after logoff and logon again. It will reset to default and you must change manually. Before that update it worked, so we must wait MS to correct this.

Comment: How do you override it? It's not clear enough from this answer

Comment: After the windows update, the problem is fixed. Just go to Advanced Keyboard Settings and set Override default input method and it will work properly.

Answer (score 2):

This was extremely annoying for me as well!

There is a solution for this. Find out the language code of the offending keyboard that starts when you log on (https://www.the-localization-tool.com/language-codes-mfc/), then open regedit, browse to HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload, and remove the string that contains that language code (it will be in form of 0000**code** instead of 0x**code**).

I had two keyboards installed, en-EN and hr-HR, even though I set input keyboard override to Croatian keyboard, it always logged me in with English keyboard active. After I removed English keyboard from that location in registry (the code was 00000409), it now logs me in only with Croatian keyboard enabled, and I don't even have any other keyboards to switch to (which is great for me because I never use EN keyboard)!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to edit the registry strings in \HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload. 
But instead of deleting the string for the unwanted layouts, like Mario Kruselj suggested, I just put the one I need in position "1" and the others in positions "2","3"...and so on.
But this is not a permanent solution. If you play with the language settings again the registry values will be overwritten and you will have to modify them again.
[keyboard layout values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUeTG.jpg)